# MockMvc post test fails

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test, mockmvc

I want to test a rest controller method of request type post that includes a request body. All other Get Methods are working expect post. I'm expecting  200 OK but it returns 417. My intention is to make it pass
I run the test and it fails. I'm new this .Can someone explain why its failing and how i can make it pass

The service class

```
 @Service
    @Transactional
    public class LoanService {

        private LoanRepository loanRepository;

        public  LoanService(LoanRepository loanRepository)
        {
          this.loanRepository = loanRepository;
        }

        public boolean createLoan(Loan loan)
        {

          Objects.requireNonNull(loan,"Loan can not be null");

         Loan loan1 = loanRepository.save(loan);
         if (loan1 != null)
         {
             return true;
         }
         return false;
        }
    }
```

The controller

```
 @RestController
    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping("/api")
    public class LoanController {

        private LoanService loanService;

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        public LoanController(LoanService loanService)
        {
            this.loanService = loanService;
        }

        @PostMapping("/createLoan")
        public ResponseEntity<String> createLoan(@RequestBody  Loan loan)
        {
            if (loanService.createLoan(loan))
            {
                return  new ResponseEntity<>(gson.toJson("Loan created successfully"), HttpStatus.OK);
            }else
            {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(gson.toJson("An error occurred while creating loan"), HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED);
            }
        }
```

The test class

```
 @SpringBootTest
    @ContextConfiguration( classes = {LoanController.class})
    @AutoConfigureMockMvc
    @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
    public class LoanControllerTest extends  JsonManager {

        //@MockBean
       // public LoanService loanService;

        @Autowired
        private MockMvc mockMvc;

        @Test
        void createLoan() throws Exception {
            Loan loan = new Loan("nehe", 450.0, "20/10/19", 200, 3.0, 200, "20/20/30");

            String inputJson = super.mapToJson(loan);

            MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(post("/api/createLoan")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                    .content(inputJson))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andReturn();

            String actual = result.getResponse().getContentAsString().replaceAll("\"","");

            assertEquals("Loan created successfully", actual);
        }
```

Json manager

```
public abstract class JsonManager {

    protected String mapToJson(Object obj) throws JsonProcessingException
    {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return  objectMapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
    }


    protected  <T> T mapFromJson(String json, Class<T> clazz)
        throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException
    {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return  objectMapper.readValue(json,clazz);
    }
}
```

The log

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /api/createLoan
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8"]
             Body = {"id":0,"borrowerName":"nehe","amountBorrowed":450.0,"dateBorrowed":"20/10/19","interestRate":200.0,"period":3.0,"deposit":200.0,"lastDateDeposited":"20/20/30"}
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.Dimes.Controllers.LoanController
           Method = com.Dimes.Controllers.LoanController#createLoan(Loan)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 417
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Vary:"Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers", Content-Type:"text/plain;charset=UTF-8", Content-Length:"39"]
     Content type = text/plain;charset=UTF-8
             Body = "An error occurred while creating loan"
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<417>
Expected :200
Actual   :417
<Click to see difference>


    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:59)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers.lambda$matcher$9(StatusResultMatchers.java:627)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:196)
    at com.Dimes.LoanControllerTest.createLoan(LoanControllerTest.java:83)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:675)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:125)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:132)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:124)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:74)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:62)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:43)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:35)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:198)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1378)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1378)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Answer (score 1):

Its's seems like `loanRepository.save(loan)` is returning null.

Are you tried to debug the test?

Comment: Why could it bet returning null

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by mocking the service class

```
 when(loanService.createLoan(any(Loan.class))).thenReturn(true);
```